# Spring Security Rest Basic authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm working with Spring security 4 XML based configuration.

This is my configuration :

```
      <security:http use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
            <security:form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"
                                 authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"
                                 />
            <security:logout success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler"/>
            <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
        </security:http>

        <security:authentication-manager id="authenticationManager">
            <security:authentication-provider>
                <security:user-service>
                    <security:user name="username" authorities="ROLE_USER" password="password"/>
                </security:user-service>
            </security:authentication-provider>
        </security:authentication-manager>

        <bean id="authenticationEntryPoint" class="package.CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint">
```

The `authenticationEntryPoint` has the following implementation :

```
public class CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {

        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
}
```

**The problem is** when I try to authenticate :

`http://localhost:8080/myApp/api/j_spring_security_check` with body : `j_password=password&j_username=username`

I have always a *401 error status* because of my custom entry point. It seems to me that *spring security is not calling the authentication-manager*. Do I miss something ?

Thanks for helping.

**Update**

Thanks for your answers, I've been working with Spring Security 3.2, I changed j_username, j_password and  j_spring_security_check to username, password and login. I still have the same problem : 401 code status : Spring Security is calling the custom authenticationEntryPoint even when I try to authenticate using a form (POST).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my `web.xml` file, the url-pattern for Spring Security filterchain is : `/api/*`

I had to add the same url-pattern to the login-processing-url : `"/api/"` in my configuration file (login-form) to make it work :

```
login-processing-url="/api/login"
```

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 3):

For Spring Security version 4, the default login processing URL is:

`http://localhost:8080/myApp/login`

(`j_spring_security_check` was used in earlier versions.)

Note that this is *form login* and has nothing to do with *HTTP Basic authentication*.

Answer (score 2):

In Spring 4 form field default names were changed from `j_username` and `j_password` to `username` and `password`. You should either change it in your request or explicitly set it in your xml config. Also login-processing-url default changed from `j_spring_security_check` to `login`.
[Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html) you can find some info about it.

Answer (score 1):

Summary of problems:

1. As [@holmis83](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1463522/holmis83) wrote, default login processing URL is `login`, see [Spring Scurity Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-form-login-attributes):

   > - **login-processing-url** Maps to the `filterProcessesUrl` property of `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`. The default value is "/login".
2. As [@pomkine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1284054/pomkine) wrote, default parameters are `username` and `password`, see [Spring Security Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-form-login-attributes):

   > - **password-parameter** The name of the request parameter which contains the password. Defaults to "password".
   > - **username-parameter** The name of the request parameter which contains the username. Defaults to "username".
3. Default HTTP method is `POST`, see [UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#setPostOnly](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.html#setPostOnly(boolean)):

   > Defines whether only HTTP POST requests will be allowed by this filter. If set to true, and an authentication request is received which is not a POST request, an exception will be raised immediately and authentication will not be attempted. The `unsuccessfulAuthentication()` method will be called as if handling a failed authentication.
   >   Defaults to `true` but may be overridden by subclasses.
4. As [@holmis83](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1463522/holmis83) wrote, you use `form-login` and this is not [HTTP Basic Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), see [Spring Security Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-form-and-basic):

   > If you want to use basic authentication instead of form login, then change the configuration to
   >
   > ```
   > <http use-expressions="false">
   >     <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
   >     <http-basic />
   > </http>
   > ```
   >
   > Basic authentication will then take precedence and will be used to prompt for a login when a user attempts to access a protected resource. Form login is still available in this configuration if you wish to use it, for example through a login form embedded in another web page.

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to use Basic Authentication, I'm configuring spring security for a REST application. when I try to authenticate using a POST it gives me a 401 code status. I know what is the difference between basic authentication and form login.